# Python - type conversion loop through dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary filled with number strings and i want to convert every of those values into binary. Here is what i tried:

```
    for k,v in ValueDict.items():
        ValueDict.update(k:bin(v))
```

However this does not work. PyCharm says "Illegal target for variable annotation", i dont understand what this means. As far as i know, variable annotation is a way of "commenting" on the types of a variable, but i dont understand how this is related to my issue...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using dictionary comprehension:

```
print({k:bin(v) for k,v in ValueDict.items()})
```

Or if version less then 2.5:

```
print(dict((k:bin(v) for k,v in ValueDict.items())))
```

Your code doesn't work from `:` in `ValueDict.update(k:bin(v))`

To use your style:

```
for k,v in ValueDict.items():
    ValueDict.update({k:bin(v)})
```

Or:

```
for k,v in ValueDict.items():
    ValueDict[k]=bin(v)
```

Comment: Oh, i didnt knew i had to use curly braces when i only want to change one entry, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation at [dict.update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return *None*.
>
> **`update()`** accepts either **another dictionary** object or an **iterable of key/value pairs** (as tuples or other iterables of length two). If keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with those key/value pairs: `d.update(red=1, blue=2)`.

Examples:

```
# dict expression
d = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
>>> {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}

# multiple updates: no loop needed
d.update( {"a" : 11, "b" : 22} )
>>> {'a': 11, 'c': 3, 'b': 22}

# multiple adds: no loop needed (also no '' around keys)
d.update( A = 111, B = 22 )
>>> {'a': 11, 'A': 111, 'c': 3, 'b': 22, 'B': 22}

# updating all keys using loop
for k,v in d.items():
    d[k]=v*2
>>> {'a': 22, 'A': 222, 'c': 6, 'b': 44, 'B': 44}
    

# add values to a list if same keys and not yet in
# providing an existing key here would overwrite that one
new_ones = ( ("X",42), ("X",4711) )
for k,v in new_ones:
    entry = d.setdefault(k,[])
    entry.append(v)
>>> {'a': 22, 'A': 222, 'c': 6, 'b': 44, 'B': 44, 'X': [42, 4711]}

# no loop - update from iterable of key/value pairs
new_ones = ( ("i",42), ("j",4711) )
d.update(new_ones)
>>> {'a': 22, 'A': 222, 'c': 6, 'b': 44, 'i': 42, 'j': 4711, 'B': 44, 'X': [42, 4711]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `dict` to `update` method.

```
for k,v in ValueDict.items():
    ValueDict.update({k:bin(v)})
```